# KSOAP get XML response

Tags: android, ksoap

I use KSOAP to access a webservice for my application. I use a SoapObject to build the request and I got an strange response (in this case strange means not XML).

I'm new with KSOAP and I need to add some changes into an existing project built on KSOAP, so to avoid using it is not an option. The code is simple, and works, but I cannot manage to parse the response.

The code that use for this is:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("PersonalID", "032676025");
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            Log.i("Webservice Output", response.toString());

            return response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The issue here is that I cannot find the XML that comes from my webservice as response. I need to get it and to parse it by myself.

The question is: **how do I obtain from the objects used in the code above the XML response (as XML)?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution: 
set **androidHttpTransport.debug = true;** before to make the WS call.

After this, you may access the request and the response like this:

```
String requestDump = androidHttpTransport.requestDump;
String responseDump = androidHttpTransport.responseDump;

Log.i("", "Requeste: " + requestDump);
Log.i("", "Response: " + responseDump);
```

Comment: can we get the raw response without debug = true. Need to authenticate the response on basis of a checksum